# Finding roots of a Legendre polynomial

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, numerical-methods, roots

> Given the following Legendre polynomials, find the roots of $p_{2}$
>
> $$p_{i}(x)=\frac{1}{2^{i}i!}\frac{d^{i}}{dx^{i}}[(x^2-1)^{i}]$$

My book says that $p_{2}(x)=x^2$ and can be adjusted to $p_{2}(x)=x^2+c$

But wikipedia says that $p_{2}$ is defined from a recursive property as $\frac{1}{2}(3x^2-1)$. So I am a little bit confused about what roots I should find. The other thing would be to plug in $i=2$ and then find the roots, but I am not sure about that method as well. Any explanation would be helpful

Comment: By Rodrigues formula $P_2(x)=\frac{1}{2}(3x^2-1)$ and it is not difficult to locate the roots of a quadratic polynomial (especially if it is an even function).

Comment: The Legendre polynomial was introduced to me in a chapter which covers ''Gaussian Quadrature''. I haven't been introduced to Rodrigues formula. Could one derive this result without Rodrigues formula?

Comment: Rodrigues' formula is exactly the formula you are using for defining Legendre polynomials: $$ P_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^n n!}\cdot\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n$$ and according to such formula $P_2(x)$ is not $x^2$ but $\frac{1}{2}(3x^2-1)$.

Comment: That is a way for defining them. Another way is to consider the monomial base $1,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots$ and apply the Gram-Schmidt algorithm with respect to the inner product $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_{-1}^{1}f(x)\,g(x)\,dx$, then choose a suitable normalization.

Comment: Okay thank you, I must have mixed something up. actually we're learning how to combine inner products with functions now, seems like your second method with gram schmidt looks interesting

Comment: Can you mention what your book is? The roots of $P_2$ clearly lie at $\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, but $P_2(x)$ is not $x^2$ and I do not get the actual meaning of "$x^2$ can be adjusted to $x^2+c$".

Comment: My book is Timothy Sauer numerical analysis. I realized that I have misread the book. They use $p_{2} =x^2+c$ to show that a set of three orthogonal polynomials on [-1,1] is { $1,x,x^2,-1/3$ }

Answer (score 1):

In order to evaluate  $$p_{i}(x)=\frac{1}{2^{i}i!}\frac{d^{i}}{dx^{i}}[(x^2-1)^{i}]$$ for $i=2$, we differentiate $$(x^2-1)^2$$ twice to get

$$ 12x^2-4$$ and divide by $8$.

This is the correct answer$$\frac{1}{2}(3x^2-1)$$

The  roots are $$x= \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$$